# Android undo drawing method on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I created some code that takes a picture and displays the picture, then the user is able to draw on the picture.

I want to implement an `undo` method. I based my code on many examples I've read. The problem is in my `onDraw` method - the examples don't use `drawBitmap` but for me I have to draw the bitmap on the canvas in order for the image to show up.

The code shown displays the image, allows drawing on the image, but does not undo the drawings. I can't figure out what's wrong/how to fix it.

```
public class PhotoView extends View {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public PhotoView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        mBitmap = mutableBitmap;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
        ****must call in order for image to show up *****
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        for (Path p : paths){
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); //real time drawing on canvas
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(mPath);
        mPath = new Path();
        //mPath.reset();
        //paths.add(mPath);
    }

    public void onClickUndo () {
        if (paths.size()>0)
        {
            paths.remove(paths.size()-1);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    public Bitmap getPic() {
        mCanvas.save();
        return mBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two things you are doing when it comes to `Paths` that the user draws.

1. In the method `touchUp()` : `mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);`
2. In `onDraw()` : `canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);`

When you call `onClickUndo()`, the `onDraw()` things gets undone. But the one in `touchUp()` is not undone. That's why your Undo doesn't seem to work. Problem is in line `mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);`

**Solution**:

 Do not draw the `mPath` on `mCanvas`. When you do this, your `mBitmap` gets changed (you are drawing your `paths` on the `mBitmap`). There is no way to undo this. And this is not what you want. If you want your `paths` in your `mBitmap`, so that you can save it in a file or so, do this finally (perhaps have a method like `save()` and do this in that method).